# Editing a program to use a do while/ while loop from user input in Java

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java, so I don't have much experience with the syntax, I have tried some tutorials online and have watched a few videos on while and do while loops in Java from a user input. However, every edit i try breaks my code. The program below takes an answer from the user, an integer from 1 to 20, and has if statements, that carry out the different scenarios. However, I am trying to make it so that it will keep asking the user for an answer, until they input 0. Here is a part of relevant code:

```
System.out.print("Type in the pokedex number of the pokemon:");
        int answer = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (answer == 1){ 
                            System.out.println(
                            "\nPokemon: " + Bulbasaur.getname() +     
                            "\nType: " + Bulbasaur.getthing_about() +
                            "\nHealth: " + Bulbasaur.gethp() +
                            "\nAttack: " + Bulbasaur.getattack() +
                            "\nDefense: " + Bulbasaur.getdefense() +      
                            "\nSpecial attack: " + Bulbasaur.getspattack() +        
                           "\nSpecial defense: " + Bulbasaur.getspdefense()+ 
                            "\nSpeed: " + Bulbasaur.getspeed() +
                            "\nTotal: " + Bulbasaur.gettotal());
        }
```

.
.
.

There are 19 other if statements similar to this (I know this is inefficient code, but i will be making it efficient if it loops). 
How would I add a do while/while loop that loops these statements until 0 is entered?

Comment: For the loop or to make the code more efficient?

Comment: For both. Arrays can store data of similar types, so by using loops, you can take each pokemon from the array and print it according to the choice.

Comment: Read up on Arrays, and I'll be posting some sample code that will help you better understand.

Comment: Okay, I will read the arrays page that you linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be more efficient if you kept the methods like `getName()` and all 'non-static', so that they could be called from objects of the classes.

If you've understood how to use `int[]`, `double[]` etc. type of Arrays, what you can do is create an array of objects of the Pokemon like so:

```
Object[] pokemon = {new Bulbasaur(), new Ivysaur(), new Venusaur()}; // etc. etc.

int answer = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
answer = answer - 1; // because arrays start at zero, not one

System.out.println("\nPokemon: " + pokemon[answer].getname() +     
"\nType: " + pokemon[answer].getthing_about() +
"\nHealth: " + pokemon[answer].gethp() +
"\nAttack: " + pokemon[answer].getattack() +
"\nDefense: " + pokemon[answer].getdefense() +      
"\nSpecial attack: " + pokemon[answer].getspattack() +        
"\nSpecial defense: " + pokemon[answer].getspdefense()+ 
"\nSpeed: " + pokemon[answer].getspeed() +
"\nTotal: " + pokemon[answer].gettotal());
```

Here's [a guide to using Objects](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts) if you need it.

By making the methods non-static, you can call them from Objects which belong to an array, and all you have to do to add more Pokemon to the array is add `, new WhateverPokemon()` to it..

Also, if you want to print the choices to the user, you can do so like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i+1+". "+ pokemon[i].getName());
}
```

If you want to add this code, then place it immediately after the `Object[] pokemon ...`.

Comment: Ok, so store pokemon in an array, but wouldn't this also mean that I will have write multiple if statements in order for the user to be able to choose which pokemon they want?

Comment: @Benny Nope, and that's the beauty of arrays. The pokemon chosen is given by `pokemon[i]`, which directly calls the pokemon of the user's choice of index.

Comment: @Benny That's why I've kept just one `System.out.println()` for the pokemon info

Comment: Oh ok, so the for loop will be used to call which pokemon the user is looking for?

Comment: @Benny I've updated the last code just now, and the for loop only shows the names of the pokemon (like giving a menu to the customer)

Comment: @Benny The loop is something extra you might want to add to inform the user what number they should enter for the desired pokemon

Comment: Ohh, this makes sense

Comment: So kinda like how the pokemon games go

Comment: I'll try it, this will definitely be more efficient than my code

Comment: @Benny If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `answer` in the loop condition. You can do the check and assignment to answer in one line

```
int answer;
while ((answer = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine())) != 0) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite intuitive implementation of what you want:

```
System.out.print("Type in the pokedex number of the pokemon:");
    int answer = -1;  // Initialize to a trivial value different from 0
    while (answer != 0) {  // It will not enter here if initialized to 0!
        answer = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (answer == 1){
            // Code from the if statement
        }  // End of if
    }  // End of while
```

As @Coffeehouse said, you should take a look at what an array is, and try to use it appropriately. It will shorten your code by quite a lot. Step by step, though :)

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks, but about the arrays, would I make ten arrays, one with with the pokemon name, type, hp, attack, defense... and then use for loops to manipulate them?

Comment: @Benny Check out my answer, maybe that could help :)

Comment: You can create your own `Pokemon` class with the specific getters (`getname()`, `getattack()`...) and then create an array of `Pokemon` which will be able to hold many different pokemons (in just one array!).

Comment: @LeSirDog I agree, but I also feel that as a beginner the OP might want to go on with his current code - which he's able to understand.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Indeed, you are totally right, although I supposed @Benny had named their class `Pokemon` and had specific getters already.